# Any way to save log files of all user per day/week/month in salesforce?

Tags: apex, community, debugging, debug

In my company ,there are 50 salesforce licence .some of them are getting some exception while using salesforce apex class programs they are not giving me good information to check where the exceptions are coming form .

Moveover Current salesforce flag log files expiration will be with in 24 hours.Difficult to manage them .20 will be the limit ,

Any way to save log files of all user per day/week/month in salesforce ?

Comment: you may want to use a custom object that will contain all the log files. So what you can do create a batch that will run every day and will create custom object record based on log files field mapping.